# My Arduino Nano sends incorrect (sensor) values

Tags: arduino, xbee

I want to develop a wireless [VOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_detector#Hydrocarbons_and_VOCs) sensor-system. I used [TGS2602](http://www.figarosensor.com/products/2602pdf.pdf), [Arduino Nano](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardNano) and [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) Pro S1.

This is my code:

```
int value ;
const int gasSensor = A0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    int value = analogRead (gasSensor);

    float volt = (value/1023.0)*5.0 ;   // Rechne die von ADC ausgegebenen Werten in Volt um
    float Rs1 = 10*(5-volt)/volt;       // Rechne den Widerstandswert
    //Serial.print("40B7DEF1");         // Sensorname
    //Serial.print("\t");               // Tabulator

    // Kalibrierungsarray der Länge N = 17
    float Rs [17] = {57.84260516,  2.200081335,  1.606762875,  1.178596714,  0.944910617,     0.865628395,  0.764262648,  0.687566798,  0.626992561,  0.567101091,  0.544815465,  0.496850952,  0.474860336,  0.474860336,  0.442046642,  0.423905489,  0.402219139};
    float ppmValue [17] = {0,  5,  10,  15,  20,  24,  28.25,  32.5,  37.75,  43.25,  48.75,  53.25,  57.75,  62.50,  67.50,  75.5,  77.5};

    if (Rs1 >= Rs [0])
    {
        float ppm = ppmValue [0];
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println(ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    // Interpolation: ppm [0;5]
    if ( Rs[1] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[0]){
        float ppm = ppmValue [0] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [0])/(Rs[0] - Rs [1] ))*(ppmValue [1] - ppmValue[0]);
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    // Interpolation: ppm [5;10]
    else if ( Rs[2] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[1]){
        float ppm = ppmValue [1] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [1])/(Rs[1] - Rs [2] ))*(ppmValue [2] - ppmValue[1]);

        //PPM Ausgabe
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    // Interpolation: ppm [10;15]
    else if ( Rs[3] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[2]){
        float ppm = ppmValue [2] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [2])/(Rs[2] - Rs [3] ))*(ppmValue [3] - ppmValue[2]);

        //PPM Ausgabe
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    // Interpolation: ppm [15;24]
    else if ( Rs[4] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[3]){
        float ppm = ppmValue [3] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [3])/(Rs[3] - Rs [4] ))*(ppmValue [4] - ppmValue[3]);

        //PPM Ausgabe
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    // Interpolation: ppm [24;28.25]
    else if ( Rs[5] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[4]){
        float ppm = ppmValue [4] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [4])/(Rs[4] - Rs [5] ))*(ppmValue [5] - ppmValue[4]);

        //PPM Ausgabe
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    // Interpolation: ppm [28.25;32.5]
    else if ( Rs[6] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[5]){
        float ppm = ppmValue [5] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [5])/(Rs[5] - Rs [6] ))*(ppmValue [6] - ppmValue[5]);
        //PPM Ausgabe
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    // Interpolation: ppm [32.5;37.75]
    else  if ( Rs[7] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[6]){
        float  ppm = ppmValue [6] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [6])/(Rs[6] - Rs [7] ))*(ppmValue [7] - ppmValue[6]);

        //PPM Ausgabe
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    // Interpolation: ppm [37.75;43.25]
    else if ( Rs[8] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[7]){
        float  ppm = ppmValue [7] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [7])/(Rs[7] - Rs [8] ))*(ppmValue [8] - ppmValue[7]);

        //PPM Ausgabe
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    // Interpolation: ppm [43.25;48.75]
    else if ( Rs[9] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[8]){
        float ppm = ppmValue [8] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [8])/(Rs[8] - Rs [9] ))*(ppmValue [9] - ppmValue[8]);

        //PPM Ausgabe
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }
    // Interpolation: ppm [48.75;53.25]
    else  if ( Rs[10] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[9]){
        float  ppm = ppmValue [9] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [9])/(Rs[9] - Rs [10] ))*(ppmValue [10] - ppmValue[9]);

        //PPM Ausgabe
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    // Interpolation: ppm [53.25;57.75]
    else if ( Rs[11] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[10]){
        float ppm = ppmValue [10] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [10])/(Rs[10] - Rs [11] ))*(ppmValue [11] - ppmValue[10]);

        //PPM Ausgabe
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    // Interpolation: ppm [57.75;62.5]
    else if ( Rs[12] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[11]){
        float  ppm = ppmValue [11] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [11])/(Rs[11] - Rs [12] ))*(ppmValue [12] - ppmValue[11]);

        //PPM Ausgabe
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    // Interpolation: ppm [62.5;67.5]
    else  if ( Rs[13] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[12]){
        float  ppm = ppmValue [12] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [12])/(Rs[12] - Rs [13] ))*(ppmValue [13] - ppmValue[12]);
        //PPM Ausgabe
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    // Interpolation: ppm [67.5;75.5]
    else  if ( Rs[14] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[13]){
        float ppm = ppmValue [13] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [13])/(Rs[13] - Rs [14] ))*(ppmValue [14] - ppmValue[13]);

        //PPM Ausgabe
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    // Interpolation: ppm [75.5;77.5]
    else if( Rs[15] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[14]){
        float ppm = ppmValue [14] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [14])/(Rs[14] - Rs [15] ))*(ppmValue [15] - ppmValue[14]);

        //PPM Ausgabe
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    else if( Rs[16] < Rs1 && Rs1 < Rs[15]){
        float ppm = ppmValue [15] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [15])/(Rs[15] - Rs [16] ))*(ppmValue [16] - ppmValue[15]);

        //PPM Ausgabe
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);}

    else if (Rs1 >= Rs [16])
    {
        float ppm = ppmValue [16];

        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    else if (Rs1 < Rs [16])
    {
        float ppm = 80;

        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");            // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");           // Tabulator

        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }

    delay(3000);
}
```

I don´t know what I'm doing wrong, but the values I'm getting are all wrong. It seems that these values aren't from the analogpin. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "are all wrong"? What do you receive?
BTW in your code you don't send the value, but you just send `1   0` whenever the value is higher than 57.84...

Comment: That is a lot of repeated code that only differs in the index into the array "Rs". It could be much shorter by doing it in a "for" loop.

Comment: Hi frarugi87, thanks a lot for your question. I receive 3,3ppm, 3,4ppm....these values are definitely not from my sensor.

Comment: Hi Peter, i´m trying to reduce my code. I´m a newbie in programming

Comment: @user3559628 What kind of help do you need?

Comment: Hi djUniversal, i want to know what i´m doing wrong. Because the value í´m getting are all wrong. Sometimes i received 0.00ppm or 80ppm.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has all of your > and < backwards. Consequently the only code running is:

```
else if (Rs1 < Rs [16])
```

While you are at it please allow me to help you change the code a bit. This is really written in long form and it will take a long time to debug/edit any code this way.

Replace all of your ifs with:

```
for ( int i = 0; i <= 16; i++ ) {
    if (Rs1 < Rs [i]) {
        if (i = 0) {
            float ppm = ppmValue [i];
        }
        else{
            float ppm = ppmValue [i-1] + ((-Rs1 + Rs [i-1])/(Rs[i-1] - Rs [i] ))*(ppmValue [i] - ppmValue[i-1]);
        }
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");
        // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");
        // Tabulator
        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
        break;
    }
    else if (Rs1 > Rs [16]) {

        float ppm = 80;
        //Serial.print ("ppm: ");
        Serial.print("1");
        // Sensorname
        Serial.print("\t");
        // Tabulator
        Serial.println (ppm);
        delay(30000);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you find yourself writing out code many times over it copy/pasting and editing just one part of it, you are probably better to use  arrays and for. You already had the arrays so you were half way there. Happy coding!

Comment: Hi djUniversal, thansk for your answers. But this code doesn´t work because i´m doing an interpolation to calculate my ppm value.

Comment: Sorry, just realised you changed the formula there (didn't see the width of the code on my phone). I have modified my code to match. Should work now. Did you try just changing the signs around? Did that work?

Comment: Hi djUniversal, i´m getting 0.00.

Comment: What is the starting sensor value?

Comment: Do a Serial.println() for value and Rs1 to check them before the loop code and follow the values through the code. Check what you would manually calculate vs code. Any issues?

Comment: I put the code together and fed 500 into value and got this: 1    0.33

Comment: Hi djUniversal, sorry for my late answer. i get the same value you get 0.31, but this value never changes. i´ve heard that the float value can´t be read with an arduino nano, is it true?

Comment: Its has no FPU but does all its floating point math in software rather than hardware. If you are doing a lot of time critical fp math you would run into trouble but it should be fine for what you are doing.

Comment: What values are being fed in vs what is coming out. Send me a sample.

Comment: what do you mean by "in vs"?

Comment: Sorry, what numbers go in and what numbers come out. I would like to see how it is calculating each number. Also update your coffee in the main question so i can see what you have modified to.